# real time display LaTeX formulas in Lyx

Tags: lyx, editors

Is there any way to display LaTeX formulas in real-time in Lyx without downloading another editor?
I have seen other posts for the same question but it is very old so I can not find the functionality the same way anymore.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by `Is there any way to display LaTeX formulas in real-time in Lyx without downloading another editor? ` that does not make much sense to me

Comment: @daleif  when I type Latex code it would be nice to have a window where I can see what will be displayed to check if my code is right

Comment: You can look at View > Code Preview Pane to see the corresponding LaTeX. Is that what you mean? Or do you mean you want to write LaTeX? If you want to write a lot of LaTeX directly, probably LyX is not the best tool for you. You might like to set Tools > Preferences > Display > Instant preview to "On". That is not real-time. Every time you make an edit you will need to move the cursor outside and let the preview refresh.